# use span to hide and show content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am new in both php and jquery. i want to use span to hide and show content in html and php. can i use jquery? if yes, what should i do? i already put the jquery script to the bottom of page. this is my code :

```
    <!-- reply -->
    <span title="fas fa-reply" name="reply" data-id="1" 
    </span>
    <!-- if span clicked show all these data... -->
    <table class="table table-borderless" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <thead class="bg-secondary pb-0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" class="pb-0">
            <p class="test text-light">Creating Reply <?php echo $rowAllPost["id"]; ?>
            </p></th>
            <th class="pb-0 text-right">
            </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <th scope="row" style="width:15rem!important;">
            <img src="<?php echo $rowViewUserNow["picture"];?>" class="rounded-circle" style=height:93px;width:81px;><br>
            <p class="ml-3"> Online</p>
            <p class="ml-2"> <?php echo $rowViewUserNow["username"];?>
            </p>
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle pr-2 pt-2"></i>Active
            <td colspan="3" class="text-justify">
            <form action="controller/doCheckPost.php" method="post">
                <textarea name="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-secondary pb-0" >
            <th colspan="3" class="pb-0">
            <button title="Cancel" class="btn" type="submit" name="cancel"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></th></button>
            <th class= "pb-0 text-right">
            <button title="Submit" class="btn" name="submit"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
            </form>
            </th>
            </th>
        </tr>
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: This should help:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to first give an id to both the span and table elements. Then you can use an [event handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery like this:

```
$('#spanId').on('click', function() {
  $('#tableId').toggle();
});
```

[Toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will show the element if it's hidden and hide it if it's visible.